# Can I connect the output of AudioTrack to microphone input?

Tags: android, audiotrack, audiorecord

Is it possible to use the `AudioTrack` class in the way that the audio signal is passed to the microphone input?

What I'm trying to achieve is some kind of interceptor, which takes the microphone input (using `AudioRecord` class), performs some transformations on the sound, and then, sends the *transformed* audio to another application, which records microphone input (it can be Skype or sound recorder).

Comment: Similar question is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384120/speaker-output-to-mic-input-without-cable-on-android

Comment: I think this question is asked from the Android user's perspective. I'm asking from the developer perspective - how can I implement these requirements in my Android application.

Comment: No, it's from developper perspective. It says want to port Linux JACK to android. Please look at the answer "As far as porting Jack to Android goes, you might take a look at this" part. It has a link who tried to port it.

Comment: Have a look at this, I believe you have a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android

Comment: Can you tell us if this helps ? :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067273/play-back-audio-from-mic-in-real-time